# Obtain SQL Server executed query history of specific database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a mechanism to obtain a history of queries executed on a specific database in SQL Server 2012? I tried with below method, but it provides the entire history of the SQL Server.

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it in this way

```
Where dbid = (Select database_id from sys.databases Where name = 'your_database_name')
```

**Full query:**

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
Where dbid = (select database_id from sys.databases Where name = 'your_database_name')
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

Comment: How can I see who has executed the query please?

Answer (score -1):

Worked query based on [@Phong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59816452/9071943)

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
where dbid = (select database_id from sys.databases where name = 'MyDataBase')
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```